# I am using the WHERE clause with OR but i am getting an error

Tags: mysql, database, macos, mariadb

I have looked online and have followed others advice such as using back-ticks and using parenthesis but im still getting this error. if anyone can help id appreciate it.

my query:

```
select p.*, a.street1, a.street2, a.cityeet1, a.street2, a.city, a.name 
from person p 
left join address a 
where (a.name = 'New Jersey' or a.name = 'Connecticut');
```

error:

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'where (a.name = 'New Jersey' or a.name = 'Connecticut')' at line 1

Comment: Try without alias in the WHERE clause, regards.

Comment: There is no join `ON` condition; but that usually doesn't stop it in mysql.

Comment: @Uueerdo Even MySQL requires an `ON` clause for outer joins.

Comment: Why are you using `LEFT JOIN` if you only want specific states?

Comment: @Barmar, ah, I never omit them myself unless by rare accident; I just see tons of people getting cross products, and never paid attention to if it was only on INNER joins or not.

Comment: Putting the relationship in the `WHERE` clause of a cross product is equivalent to putting it in the `ON` clause of inner join. But they're not equivalent for outer join, because you need a specific relationship to determine when to return null rows.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the join values - possibly something like this:

**join address a ON (p.address_id = a.id)**

```
select p.*, a.street1, a.street2, a.cityeet1, a.street2, a.city, a.name from person p left join address a ON (p.address_id = a.id) where (a.name = 'New Jersey' or a.name = 'Connecticut');
```

Where the two fields **join** the tables (indicate the matching values)

Also, it looks like you have a typo in the field names (a.cityeet1)

Comment: thank you i ended up not using left join and just joined the tables and used where clauses to combine foreign keys.